# PHP Curl download full large file of .tbz and .tbz.md5 extension

Tags: php, curl, download

I am using CURL to download 4 files from the url for which i have to authenticate myself. and i am authenticating myself with CURL only. But the problem is when i download data it only download 1KB of each file. I tried various methods given on SO. But none of them are working for me. My CURL-PHP code is

```
<?php

  require ('dbconfig/dbconfig.php'); //database connection.
  ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  $username = "user";
  $password = "password";
  $url = "http://domain-name/contents/";

  global $ch;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1);
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  $r = time()-(24*60*60); 
  $dateit = date("Ymd", $r);

  $file1 = "aaa".$dateit.".tbz";
  $file2 = "aaa".$dateit.".tbz.md5";
  $file3 = "bbb".$dateit.".tbz";
  $file4 = "bbb".$dateit.".tbz.md5";

  $arr = array($file1, $file2, $file3, $file4);

  for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {

    $url = "http://domain-name/content/current/".$arr[$i];

    $writefn = function($ch, $chunk) { 
      static $data='';
      static $limit = 500; // 500 bytes, it's only a test

      $len = strlen($data) + strlen($chunk);
      if ($len >= $limit ) {
        $data .= substr($chunk, 0, $limit-strlen($data));
        echo strlen($data) , ' ', $data;
        return -1;
      }
      $data .= $chunk;
      return strlen($chunk);
    };

    $ch = curl_init();
    $fp = fopen("adminArea/folder/".$arr[$i], 'w+');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, '0-500');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, $writefn);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

    curl_exec ($ch);

  }

  fclose($fp);
  curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Firstly i am authenticating myself then in for loop for all four i am using curl to download data. I got this curl code too from SO. Tried a lot of ways to do the same.

Any help or idea will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

code worked for me. I added curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); both times as firstly it will authenticate and return response and then download file for me from other url.

```
 // Set cURL options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);

// Do it
curl_exec ($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlbase.$file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$fp = fopen("adminArea/folder/$file", 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

// Do it
curl_exec ($ch);

// Close pointers    
fclose($fp);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly - it will help you spot errors much more easily...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is most likely to do with the callback write function. I can;t quite work out exactly what this was supposed to achieve as it is, but it certainly isn't doing you any favours. Indeed, it seems to me like there's a lot of code there that is not required for what you describe.

Try this:

```
<?php

  // Database connection - do you need this here? You never use it...
  require ('dbconfig/dbconfig.php');

  // While developing
  ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  // The details of the destination
  $username = "user";
  $password = "password";
  $urlbase = "http://domain-name/content/current/";

  // Create the file list
  $dateit = date("Ymd", strtotime('-1 day'));
  $files = array("aaa$dateit.tbz", "aaa$dateit.tbz.md5", "bbb$dateit.tbz", "bbb$dateit.tbz.md5");

  // Loop the file list
  foreach ($files as $file) {

    // Create pointers
    $ch = curl_init($urlbase.$file);
    $fp = fopen("adminArea/folder/$file", 'w+');

    // Set cURL options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

    // Do it
    curl_exec ($ch);

    // Close pointers    
    fclose($fp);
    curl_close($ch);

  }

?>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i got your point of minimal code usage. i tried your way (clear one), but my problem is still the same 1KB data file of each of the four files.

Comment: Interesting - I thought the issue would be that callback function, which I have removed. Possibly the server is closing the connection after it has sent 1KB of data? Are you developing this on a machine that you can install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on? If so, do it and watch the network traffic while the requests are made, to verify that the server is actually sending you more than 1KB of data, and look for any other elements of the request that may be causing the problem (like a `Range:` header or something).

Comment: thanks your code helped me alot with few adjustments. UPDATE is the code worked for me. :) thanks again.